# How to calculate complexity of an algorithm which calls a subroutine?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

Consider the following example:

Algorithm $A$ has Algorithm $B$ as its subroutine. The running time of algorithm $A$ without counting the time spent running the algorithm $B$ subroutine is $O(n^4)$. One call of algorithm $B$ takes $O(n^3)$ time. In a single run of algorithm $A$, algorithm $B$ is called at most $10n^2$ times.

What is the running time of algorithm $A$ including subroutines?

a. $O(n^4)$

b. $O(n^9)$

c. $O(n^7)$

d. $O(n^6)$

Comment: This may come as news to your teacher, but (a) is the only one that might be wrong. Read the definition of Big-O.

Comment: @gnasher729 my answer was O(n^5). Since total cost of running B would be O(n^3 * 10n^2). If this is correct, I agree that all answers  except "a" satisfy the definition of Big-oh. But I assume the question expects the tightest bound which would be option d. Am I correct?

Comment: @RodrikTheReader We've no idea if your interpretation of the question is correct: you need to ask the person who wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence: "In a single run of algorithm $A$, algorithm $B$ is called at most $10n^2$ times" is vague. If it means in each iteration of $A$, then as each time the calling $B$ takes $10n^2\times O(n^3) = O(n^5)$, we can say $A$ will be run in $n^4 \times O(n^5) = O(n^9)$.

On the other hand, if it means in all round of $A$, it calls $10n^2$ times $B$, as you said the time complexity would be $O(n^5)$.